# powershell script to get size of "itune(s)" folders on our server

Tags: powershell, directory, dir, get-childitem

I'm still new to PowerShell and trying to figure the best way to get the size of individual Itunes folders on our server.  There are multiple folders and they are all located in the user profiles.  This is the script i have so far but it doesnt show all the individual folders.

```
#Gets a list of all itunes folders 
$dirOfItunes = dir  -Recurse -Filter "iTunes Media" -ErrorAction silentlycontinue

Write-Host "list of itunes folders found: " $dirOfItunes 
ForEach ($i in $dirOfItunes) 
{
   $UserItuneFolder = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum)

   Write-Host "details of Itunes folders found:  " Write-Host $UserItuneFolder.get_Sum()

   write-host "folder name:  " $i.FullName

   "size " + "{0:N2}" -f ($UserItuneFolder.sum / 1MB) + " MB"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the $i (in the foreach loop) after get-childitem (you want to know the total size of $i, right?)

This should do what you want:

```
#Gets a list of all itunes folders 
$dirOfItunes = dir  -Recurse -Filter "iTunes Media" -ErrorAction silentlycontinue

Write-Host "list of itunes folders found: " $dirOfItunes 
ForEach ($i in $dirOfItunes) 
{
   $UserItuneFolder = (Get-ChildItem $i.fullname -Recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
   Write-Host "details of Itunes folders found:  " ([int] $UserItuneFolder.sum)
   write-host "folder name:  " $i.FullName
   "size " + "{0:N2}" -f ($UserItuneFolder.sum / 1MB) + " MB"
}
```

Comment: I want the sub total for each itunes folder found.

Comment: That's what you get in this example, no?

Comment: in the results i received the following: List of itunes folders found: iTunes Media iTunes Media iTunes Media iTunes Media iTunes Media iTunes Media iTunes Media iTunes Media iTunes Media iTunes Media iTunes Media
ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\sbsadmin\iTunes Media' because it does not exist. 
 $UserItuneFolder = (Get-ChildItem <<<<  $i -Recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
line:6 char37
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\sbsadmin\iTunes Media:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
line:8 char 76

Comment: Can you replace $i by $I.fullname (after get-childitem)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if im doing the right thing posting this as a answer because theres not enough room in the comments but this is the final code i used.  Thanks  jon Z for your help in solving the issue :-)

```
#Gets a list of all itunes folders 
$dirOfItunes = dir L:\Users\FolderRedirections -Recurse -Filter "iTunes Media" -ErrorAction silentlycontinue

#print list of folders found to the screen 
Write-Host "list of itunes folders found: "
ForEach ($A in $dirOfItunes) 
    {
    write-host "    " $A.fullname 
    }

#Get the total size of each folder 
ForEach ($i in $dirOfItunes) 
{
   $UserItuneFolder = (Get-ChildItem $i.fullname -Recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
   Write-Host "Size of folders in bytes:  " ([int] $UserItuneFolder.sum)
   write-host "Folder name:  " $i.FullName
   "size of folder: " + "{0:N2}" -f ($UserItuneFolder.sum / 1MB) + " MB"

}
```

Comment: [Here](http://svn.lando.us/joey/Public/SO/8729014/foo.ps1) is a cleaned-up version of that script. I thought I'd replace a few poor PowerShell idioms by better ones. Don't forget that you're dealing with objects (and cmdlets are smart enough to figure that out) and that you have a pipeline.